# Check for orient of json file before reading to dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have to change a json file that was inputted by a user into a dataframe and I need to output the results for some summary statistics. The problem is I don't know what orient the json file will be in.
Is there any way to check the orient of a json file before reading to Pandas dataframe?

Comment: Can `orient` be anything for the file you consider? You could try to read a small chunk of the file using `chunksize` and `lines=True` and then, for each possible value of `orient` do a `try except` statement to test if the file was read in the right format. See the docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to some degree.

The [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) has the following:

```
The format of the JSON string:
‘split’ : dict like {‘index’ -> [index], ‘columns’ -> [columns], ‘data’ -> [values]}
‘records’ : list like [{column -> value}, … , {column -> value}]
‘index’ : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}
‘columns’ : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}
‘values’ : just the values array
‘table’ : dict like {‘schema’: {schema}, ‘data’: {data}}
```

In cases where `orient='index'` or `orient='columns'`, there isn't any way to determine which one it is without further information about what we expect column names or row names to look like (custom logic).

```py
# Assuming you have user_json to a native python object using the `json` module
orient = None
if isinstance(user_json, list):
    if not user_json or isinstance(user_json[0], list):
        orient = 'values'
    elif isinstance(user_json[0], dict):
        orient = 'records'
elif isinstance(user_json, dict):
    if (set(user_json.keys()) == {'data', 'schema'}
            and isinstance(user_json['schema'], dict)
            and isinstance(user_json['data'], list):
        orient = 'table'
    elif set(user_json.keys()) == {'columns', 'index', 'data'}:
        orient = 'split'
    # else custom logic to determine if orient = 'columns' OR 'index'?
```